# Stain deck joists / frame?

Tags: wood, deck

I had a new set of stairs / mini deck, put in with treated wood,  joists are taped,  all deck boards and handrails are composite material.   The stairs don't get a lot of sunlight and get moldy every two years and need to get pressure washed.  Would staining the framing help with the mold?  Any reason not stain the framing and exposed joists and stairs with stain?

Only thing contractor suggested was to wait a year to let the wood breathe since it was pretty green.

Comment: he is right. stain works best on dry wood.

Comment: look for  `Mold Resistant | Exterior Stains`